# Powershell script to cut/paste a specific line to the top

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to write a Powershell script that will look into a text file, find the one line in the document that has non-numbers in it, and move it to the top. (The file is basically a data extract and for unknown reasons the header row gets moved down to a random location in the file. I want to run a script that automatically moves it back up to the top.)

Has anyone had any experience with this kind of thing before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$File = 'C:\File.txt'
$Header = 'Name      Number      Something'

$Content = Get-Content -Path $File

Set-Content -Path $File -Value $Header
$Content | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_ -ne $Header } | Add-Content -Path $File
```

1. Store the name of the file in `$File`
2. If the header is static, you can store it in a variable `$Header`
3. Get the content of the file and store it in a variable `$Content`
4. Set the content of the `$File` to just the `$Header`
5. Take `$Content` where it is not equal to `$Header` and then add each line to `$File` through the use of piping

Answer (score 0):

A) Get contents of file

B) Looks for a line with no digits using Regex

C) Looks for content with digits

D) combines both lists putting header at the top ",$header + $body"

E) Saves the List to file

```
$File = "C:\Test.txt"
$content = get-content $File
$header = $content | where-object {$_ -notmatch "\d"} | ForEach-Object { "$_"}
$body = $content | where-object {$_ -match "\d"} | ForEach-Object { "$_"}
,$header + $body | out-file $File
```